# External USB Port Damaged

Tags: windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive

So here's the basics. I work in a bit of a cramped area and tend to, once and a while, trip over my cords pulling my External Hard Drive (i know that's not good for it). So this morning seems to have had the final straw and the Drive will not connect to my computer. It's still getting power and working as it makes noise. However it will not connect to the computer. i have tested the cords on my other USB drive and it connects fine so i know it's not the power or connector cable so that logic leads me to assume it's the internal USB port. It concerns me because i have about a terabyte and a half of work on there. Please what do?
It's a seagate model srd00f2 (if this is any help)

Comment: you may give it a try with another USB cable, but if that doesn't help, then your only choice is to take it to a professional for repair. Any attempt to repair it at home can make it even worse and more expensive to repair.

Comment: If its the connector cable, buy a new one online. Otherwise, Plug in your hard drive to another usb port.

Comment: Remove the hard drive from the enclosure, install hard drive in new usb enclosure, problem solved,

Answer (score 0):

USB ports are somewhat fragile over time. What sometimes happens is the metal housing bends so that it is no longer a snug fit with the contacts, which is what sounds like happened to you.  For a solution, it really depends how comfortable you are with repairing your own electronics. Me, personally, I would order a new USB module and replace the one on the circuit board by un-soldering the old one, and re-soldering the new one on.

If you do not feel comfortable doing this, then you could either see if the company offers any sort of replacement / fix option or find a local shop that will do it for you. If these options don't work for you then of course the last option is to replace the whole enclosure. If this is what it comes down to then you may as well try repairing it yourself since you will be out nothing if you ruin it in that case.

Do keep in mind that it is more than likely the enclosure itself and not the actual drive. If you get a new enclosure or fix the existing one, make sure you take the hard drive out. The hard drive can either be plugged in again once done or put into a new enclosure. No data will be lost as the drive itself will not be touched.

Different device but similar idea:
http://hackaday.com/2007/11/08/how-to-replace-a-mini-usb-port-on-your-cellphone/